# Is it possible to create SSL CSR with non-latin Organization name

Tags: ssl, character-encoding, ssl-certificate, csr

I'm implementing **SSL** for my site and, because it is targeted at Ukrainian market (at least for now) I entered **Organization name** with **cyrillic** letters when created **CSR** file using **openssl** under **Linux**.

I then created **self-signed** certificate for testing purposes but when I view **certificate info** in **Chrome** browser I see wrongly decoded letters instead of provided name in cyrillic.

Also when I submit my CSR to tools like [CSR Decoder](https://www.sslshopper.com/csr-decoder.html) they also fail to show correct Organization name in Ukrainian.

I tried to google for documentation on this but can't find relevant information...

1. Could you please advise whether it's possible to use **non-latin** charset in **Organization** name of **CSR**?
2. Will users be able to see this in major browsers?
3. Is it possible to specify State and City field in non-latin charset as well?
4. Does this depend on Certificate Authority i.e. will this work when **CA** approves my identity?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I wouldn't worry too much about the CSR. It's what the CA does with it that matters. In general, it will ignore what you put in the DN and issue a certificate with a Subject DN containing only what it has verified by other means (e.g. web form, paper work, ... depending on the validation method). It's what your CA does you should worry about, the CSR itself will probably have little to do with what you get (besides providing a way to convey your public key).

Comment: **Thanks** for the answer! I'll then check how my **CA** will process **CSR** with **cyrillic** letters and report back on result.